# SQL Cursor to check number of string concate it and store it in temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, temp-tables

I am having one table containing 3 Columns FirstName, LastName, Salary So what i have to do is that i need to make one temporary variable table then i need to perform the operation on Column FirstName as checking the Length of each field of FirstName column then if the length is below or equal to 5 then it must print name_length if the length is above 5 then it must print name only in another temporary table. i want result in only one table.

EX:- Rohan then it will print in temporary table as Rohan_5. if FirstName is prasad then it will give only prasad.

So please help me with this.

```
DECLARE @fn varchar(50)

DECLARE @ln varchar(50)

DECLARE @sal int

DECLARE zxcv CURSOR FOR

SELECT FirstName, LastName, Salary FROM Persons

OPEN zxcv

FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv
INTO @fn, @ln, @sal

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN

 IF LEN(@fn)<=5

 BEGIN

 select concat(FirstName, '_', LEN(FirstName))as FirstName, LastName, Salary from Persons where LEN(FirstName) <= 5 

  END

 ELSE

 BEGIN

 select FirstName, LastName, Salary from Persons where LEN(FirstName) > 5

 END

FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv
    INTO @fn, @ln, @sal

 END

 CLOSE zxcv;
```

[image]DEALLOCATE zxcv;

Comment: As the deleted answer said, there are set-based approaches to solving this problem. It's yet another in a long series of "use a cursor in a completely inappropriate manner" "learning exercise" that doesn't teach you how to use SQL *well*. If it's optional, skip it.

Answer (score 1):

Fine, we'll "use" a cursor, but we'll go passive-aggressive in the comments for whoever told you to use a cursor here:

```
--This whole script should just be the first select used to define the cursor

DECLARE @firstname varchar(50)
DECLARE @lastname varchar(50)
DECLARE @salary int

--But we've been told to use a cursor
CREATE TABLE #Result(FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50), Salary int)
DECLARE zxcv CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN LEN(FirstName) <= 5
        THEN concat(FirstName, '_', LEN(FirstName))
    ELSE
        FirstName END,
    LastName,
    Salary FROM Persons;

OPEN zxcv
FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv
INTO @firstname, @lastname, @salary;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    --See how pointless the actions taken in the cursor loop are now?
    INSERT INTO #Result (FirstName,LastName,Salary)
    VALUES (@firstname,@lastname,@salary);

    FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv
    INTO @firstname, @lastname, @salary;
END

CLOSE zxcv;
DEALLOCATE zxcv;

--If for some odd reason, we do need this temp table, it should be a single INSERT ... SELECT
--using the above SELECT
SELECT * FROM #Result;
```

Unlike you, I'm apparently not using a weird SKU where we have to pay by the letter for naming our variables, so I've given them more descriptive names (apologies, once I start writing passive aggressive, it's a difficult mode to get out of :-)

The problems in your approach are a) Every `SELECT` that isn't assigning variables, defining a cursor or following an `INSERT` is going to generate a separate result set and b) You're requerying the base table (rather than relying on your other variables) inside the cursor loop, so bringing in other rows unrelated to the current row.

As pointed out in the comments, this *should* just be:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN LEN(FirstName) <= 5
        THEN concat(FirstName, '_', LEN(FirstName))
    ELSE
        FirstName END,
    LastName,
    Salary FROM Persons;
```

Or if we need the temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Result(FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50), Salary int)
INSERT INTO #Result (FirstName,LastName,Salary)
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN LEN(FirstName) <= 5
        THEN concat(FirstName, '_', LEN(FirstName))
    ELSE
        FirstName END,
    LastName,
    Salary FROM Persons;
```

Comment: This just screams of being a horribly contrived school assignment from a teacher who doesn't understand how data works. Hopefully the OP gets out of this class and learns a better way to handle data. Your answer had me laughing hysterically. Thanks!!!

Comment: can you please suggest using loops (IF else) ...like reading the data using conditions i.e. <=5, and by insert statement storing it in a temporary table variable and by using final select statement we are getting the output... plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without the cursor.
Please find below Query for same.

```
declare @Persons_Temp as table
(
FirstName varchar(20),
LastName varchar(20),
Salary INT
)

INSERT INTO @Persons_Temp
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(FirstName) <= 5 THEN FirstName + '_' + convert(varchar(20),LEN(FirstName)) 
ELSE FirstName END, LastName, Salary 
FROM Persons


SELECT * FROM @Persons_Temp
```

You can also Use a temporary table instead of the variable table.

Comment: They had already rejected a (since deleted) non-cursor solution. I realise you're unable to see that currently but they stated "Actually the task was to do with help of cursor."

Comment: can you please suggest using loops (IF else) ...like reading the data using conditions i.e. <=5, and by insert statement storing it in a temporary table variable and by using final select statement we are getting the output... plz help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Use with cursor than you can use as per below,

```
DECLARE @fn varchar(50)
DECLARE @ln varchar(50)
DECLARE @sal int

declare @Persons_Temp as table
(
FirstName varchar(20),
LastName varchar(20),
Salary INT
)

DECLARE zxcv CURSOR FOR
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Salary FROM Persons

OPEN zxcv

FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv
INTO @fn, @ln, @sal

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@fn)<=5
         BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Persons_Temp
            SELECT concat(FirstName, '_', LEN(FirstName))as FirstName, LastName, Salary from Persons where LEN(FirstName) <= 5 
         END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Persons_Temp
            select FirstName, LastName, Salary from Persons where LEN(FirstName) > 5
        END

FETCH NEXT FROM zxcv INTO @fn, @ln, @sal
END
CLOSE zxcv;
deallocate zxcv;

select * from @Persons_Temp;
```